# Node.js + Oracledb + executeMany + batchErrors + Promise: does not execute all if one error

Tags: node.js, promise, node-oracledb, executemany

iam using BatchError with executeMany

if no errors.. everything is ok

but if one error or more .. it doesn't execute. it gives rowsAffected = error row number

my code:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

async function post(req, res, next) {
    try {
      let user = {};
      user = await create();
  
      res.status(201).json(user);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  }
  
  module.exports.post = post;


  const sql =
  `INSERT INTO TABLE (
     USER_CODE, 
     USER_NAME,
     STAFF_ID,
     ROLE_ID,
     TEAM_CODE,
     GRP_ID,
     MOBILE_NUMBER
   ) VALUES (
     :USER_CODE,
     :USER_NAME,
     :STAFF_ID,
     :ROLE_ID,
     :TEAM_CODE,
     :GRP_ID,
     :MOBILE_NUMBER
   )`;

  async function create() {

    const data = [
      {"USER_CODE":600, "user_name": "att1", "staff_id": 660, "role_id": 1, "team_code": 20, "grp_id": 1, "mobile_number": "0101"},
      {"USER_CODE":600, "user_name": "att2", "staff_id": 661, "role_id": 1, "team_code": 20, "grp_id": 1, "mobile_number": "0102"},
      {"USER_CODE":602, "user_name": "att3", "staff_id": 662, "role_id": 1, "team_code": 20, "grp_id": 1, "mobile_number": "0103"}
   ];

    let opts = {};

    let result = await manyExecute(sql, data, opts);
 
    return result;
  }
  
  module.exports.create = create;

function manyExecute(statement, binds, opts) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let conn;
  
      opts.outFormat = oracledb.OBJECT;
      opts.autoCommit = true;
      opts.batchErrors = true;

      console.log(opts);
  
      try {
        conn = await oracledb.getConnection();
  
        result = await conn.executeMany(statement, binds, opts);
  
        resolve(result);
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      } finally {
        if (conn) { // conn assignment worked, need to close
          try {
            await conn.close();
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
  
  module.exports.manyExecute = manyExecute;
```

if i executed above code, this error appears (USER_CODE is pk):

> {
> "rowsAffected": 2,
> "batchErrors": [
> {
> "errorNum": 1,
> "offset": 1
> }
> ]
> }

i expected rowsAffected = 3
also, first item not added to TABLE

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO!. What kind of errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding commit() to my code solved my problem

```
function manyExecute(statement, binds, opts) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let conn;
  
      opts.outFormat = oracledb.OBJECT;
      opts.autoCommit = true;
      opts.batchErrors = true;

      console.log(opts);
  
      try {
        conn = await oracledb.getConnection();
  
        result = await conn.executeMany(statement, binds, opts);
  
        resolve(result);
        await conn.commit();

      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      } finally {
        if (conn) { // conn assignment worked, need to close
          try {
            await conn.close();
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
  
  module.exports.manyExecute = manyExecute;
```

Thanks to Dan McGhan, thank you all for help :)

Comment: Didn't I twice tell you two weeks ago to do an explicit `commit()`???  PS. stop using promises with async/await since that style already returns promises :)

Comment: Other comments: since you are not executing a query, there is no point setting `outFormat`.  And there is no point setting `autocommit` if you are going to explicitly commit.  Finally you have `batchErrors` enabled but are not checking those errors so you could be missing data value that should be inserted (after they have been fixed).

Comment: thanks very much Christopher Jones. i read your comment now. iam a new user here and i didn't get it first time. thanks again.
how could i check errors?

Answer (score 0):

From the [node-oracledb documentation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#executemanyoptbatcherrors):

> Note that some classes of error will always return via the
> `executeMany()` callback error object, not as batch errors.

It's possible you are seeing one of these cases.  Can you update your question with a [runnable testcase](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that triggers the error?

Don't forget that autocommit is ignored if `batchErrors` is in effect and there are errors.

Comment: {
  rowsAffected: 2,
  batchErrors: [
    [Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TABLE.PK) violated] {
      errorNum: 1,
      offset: 1
    }
  ]
}

Comment: this error raised while trying to add 3 rows
first row id:600
2nd row id:600
3rd row id:601

Comment: That information is not a runnable testcase.  Unless you give one (and give data) I don't want to waste everyone's time guessing what your problem it.

Comment: And RTM about autocommit behaviour with batcherrors.

Comment: That still not _runnable_.  And there's no CREATE TABLE statement. My best guess is that you are not doing the require explicit commit after data errors are identified.  PS there's no need to use promises in `manyExecute()` - and they make the code hard to get correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems USER_CODE is defined as a primary key, which means it must be unique throughout the table. You have two rows with same USER_CODE, which violates the unique constraint set, which means only one of the two is being inserted while the other fails. To fix this,use unique value for USER_CODE for every row, if it is not possible to make it unique, then you need to rethink your schema design and make USER_CODE a non-primary key column, you will need to find another column to use as a pk.